# Como personalizar o editor do Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ide

Gostaria de obter alguma ferramenta que personalizasse o editor do Delphi. Apesar de ser um ótimo editor, com recursos integrados com a interface de componentes que gera e atualiza código automaticamente; editores mais novo como o do eclipse contém recursos de identação que seriam muito úteis no Delphi.

Gostaria de recursos como os mostrados nas figuras abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só para constar: não é uma foto do meu monitor, é uma imagem que retirei do cabeçalho de um blog.

Comment: Não entendo porque a pergunta foi colocado em suspensa como baseada em opiniões. É uma pergunta com respostas certas ou erradas. Ele não está perguntando qual o melhor addon para o Delphi, está perguntando qual ferramenta pode o ajudar a conseguir os features que ele quer, e deixou bem claro quais são eles.

Comment: Pessoal, o que vocês acham de editar essa pergunta, deixar ela menos genérica de modo que o título e o corpo explicitamente digam que o usuário quer "identação/ocultar" em vez de algo tão amplo como aperfeiçoar?

Comment: Creio que se o título for alterado para **"Endentação e esconder/exibir de blocos de código do editor Delphi"** e haja uma ou outra alteração no corpo ela possa ser reaberta. Como fazemos nesse caso?

Comment: Como disse nosso amigo @ArthurdeAndrade é uma pergunta com uma resposta objetiva, não baseada em opiniões, porem poderia ser fechada como descontextualizada por não se tratar de um problema de programação mas sim duvidas sobre o uso de uma IDE, nesse caso ainda acho que não deveria ser fechada pois se existe a tag IDE, significa que está dentro do escopo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara tem um plugin bom e com muita utilizadade [Cnpack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en). Eu utilizo ele na empresa em que trabalho e auxilia bastante.

Não se assuste, ele é chines. Mas não tem problema nenhum pode instalar e configurar. Também é bem simples a instalação. Agora a configuração das coisas tem que fuçar bastante, pois existem muitas opções.

Comment: Como assim Chinês? Consegui esta ferramenta em português! hehehe. Procure no site dele que já tem uma atualização em várias linguas.

Comment: Assim, mas digo quem desenvolve. É que uma vez indiquei para o pessoal e eles ficaram meio desconfiado. rsrs

Comment: http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en

Comment: +1. Uso o CnPack a bastante tempo e é realmente uma ferramenta impressionante. Adiciona muito a IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Outra alternativa para o Cnpack é o [GExpert](http://www.gexperts.org/), parece que tem as mesma ferramentas do Cnpack, menos o esquema de cores e endentação. Particularmente prefiro assim, acho que deixa a tela muito poluida quando ativa esse recurso no Cnpack.

Outra dica é o [Delphi Speed UP](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/delphispeedup/) ajuda e muito na velocidade de load do proprio Delphi, e quando você utilizar o code completion (Ctrl + Space)

Outra dica é o site [Delphi About](http://delphi.about.com/od/toppicks/tp/aatpaddin.htm) pois ele possui um lista de plugins bem interessantes para Delphi.

Comment: +1. Cara muito boa a tua dica do Delphi Speed UP. Eu uso regularmente o GExpert e o CnPack combinados, mas o Speed Up eu não conhecia. Uso o Delphi 2006, fiz alguns testes sem o Speed Up, tempos de abertura de 6.12s, 6.06s e 6.03s. Já com o Speed Up abaixaram para 4.12s, 4.16s e 4.11s. 21% mais rápido na abertura. Sem contar o parse do projeto, que também melhorou.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo o [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) em conjunto com apenas uma ou duas funcionalidades do GExpert. Um extra bacana que recomendo é o [Delphi IDE Theme Editor](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-ide-theme-editor/).

Tudo isso junto torna usar Delphi um pouco mais agradável. Pelo menos pra mim.

O que eu mais queria, era um jeito de utilizar um editor externo para poder codar Delphi no Emacs.